# Python import command not finding module that exists

Tags: python, windows, python-2.7

I presently have Python 2.7 installed, and have been attempting to get my pygeoprocessing module to work correctly (which appears to have been installed correctly).  This is the version of Idle Python I am running:
"Python 2.7.10 (default, May 23 2015, 09:44:00) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32"
When I type in "import pygeoprocessing" from the Idle command line, this is the error message . . .

---

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#2>", line 1, in <module>
    import pygeoprocessing
  File "C:\Python27\ArcGISx6410.4\lib\site-packages\pygeoprocessing\__init__.py", line 10, in <module>
    from geoprocessing import *
  File "C:\Python27\ArcGISx6410.4\lib\site-packages\pygeoprocessing\geoprocessing.py", line 25, in <module>
    import scipy.interpolate
  File "C:\Python27\ArcGISx6410.4\lib\site-packages\scipy\interpolate\__init__.py", line 160, in <module>
    from .interpolate import *
  File "C:\Python27\ArcGISx6410.4\lib\site-packages\scipy\interpolate\interpolate.py", line 15, in <module>
    import scipy.linalg
  File "C:\Python27\ArcGISx6410.4\lib\site-packages\scipy\linalg\__init__.py", line 161, in <module>
    from .misc import *
  File "C:\Python27\ArcGISx6410.4\lib\site-packages\scipy\linalg\misc.py", line 5, in <module>
    from . import blas
  ***File "C:\Python27\ArcGISx6410.4\lib\site-packages\scipy\linalg\blas.py", line 155, in <module>
    from scipy.linalg import _fblas
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

---

When I navigated to the folder mentioned ( . . . scipy\linalg\blas.py) I found that both blas.py and _fblas were present.  Therefore I don't know why I got that last import error.
Is there something I can check?
Thanks!

Comment: Maybe the DLL is missing a dependency. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22221427/importerror-dll-load-failed-the-specified-procedure-could-not-be-found-python for suggestions.

Comment: I will try using dependency walker and let you know how it goes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are on a windows box you may want to verify whether you have the 64-bit or the 32-bit version of python installed. That has caused problems for me in the past.

Comment: I installed a 32 bit version of Python.  However, I use the 64 bit Python that comes with the installation of ArcGIS.  Therefore, the path to my Python27 is C:\Python27\ArcGISx6410.4

Answer (score 1):

If the above listed methods do not work, try installing the module with pip.
And then try importing it.

C.f. [How do I install pip on Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4750806/416224)

Comment: I did install pygeoprocessing using pip.  It also installed numpy and scipy at the same time.

Comment: Yeah, it does come included in the module.But still it might be working now for you.Check by importing the module.