# Cannot install PyQt5 for Python 3.5.2 in my Windows 10

Tags: python, qt, matplotlib, python-3.5, pyqt5

I have installed Anaconda3, with Python 3.5.2.
I'm trying to run an example script and for the line `import matplotlib.pyplot as plt` I get the error

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
  File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\pyplot.py", line 113, in <module>
    _backend_mod, new_figure_manager, draw_if_interactive, _show = pylab_setup()
  File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\__init__.py", line 60, in pylab_setup
    [backend_name], 0)
  File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\backend_qt5agg.py", line 16, in <module>
    from .backend_qt5 import (
  File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\backend_qt5.py", line 18, in <module>
    import matplotlib.backends.qt_editor.figureoptions as figureoptions
  File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\qt_editor\figureoptions.py", line 20, in <module>
    import matplotlib.backends.qt_editor.formlayout as formlayout
  File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\qt_editor\formlayout.py", line 56, in <module>
    from matplotlib.backends.qt_compat import QtGui, QtWidgets, QtCore
  File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\qt_compat.py", line 137, in <module>
    from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified procedure could not be found.

Process finished with exit code 1
```

I've tried to Google the issue and found a solution to install PyQt5 via pip.
I've tried to do it and get the following error: `PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'C:\\Users\\MY_USER\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-build-9t4n1ox1\\pyqt5\\PyQt5/Qt/qml/QtQuick/Controls/Private/CalendarUtils.js'`

I really don't know how to go on from here...any ideas? Thanks

Comment: Following the traceback I think you can find an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22221427/importerror-dll-load-failed-the-specified-procedure-could-not-be-found-python)

Answer (score 0):

I ended up "hacking" pip's `__init__.py` file to save the built package in Desktop and not in AppData, then I took the folder's contents and copied it to \Lib\site-packages directory.

Thanks for the help attempts :)